# How to change Colors of a BitmapImage

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net

I'm doing some drawings in a canvas I defined in an WPF(!) window.

```
 <Canvas x:Name="cBoard" Margin="0,26,-0.2,0.2" AllowDrop="True" />
```

I added some PNG files to my project and marked them so they get added by compiling. They are all black & white.

```
Dim img As New Image
Dim imgSrc As ImageSource
imgSrc = New BitmapImage(New Uri("/Resources/picture.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute))
img.Source = imgSrc
cBoard.Children.Add(img)
```

Works fine. But now I want to enable the user to set the color of the picture. I found a lot of examples(Byte-By-Byte or CorlorMap) how to do this with "Bitmap" used in WinForms/GDI+ but none how to do this with "BitmapImage" like WPF uses them. Any ideas?

Beacuse I couldn't find any solutions I tried converting the BitmapImage to System.Drawing.Bitmap, change all the colors like the examples I found, an convert it all back as an Workaround. Sadly I don't get the System.Drawing Methods running. They all throw errors at some point beacuse of the relative Adress in the URI. Again if anyone has any idea how to change the colors rightaway this is not nessaray.

Regards and thanks for any help
stan

Comment: [WriteableBitmap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap) Class. Its `BackBufferStride` is used much like the `BitmapData.Stride`. Its `BackBuffer` as the `BitmapData.Scan0` pointer.

Comment: There's no reason to use a relative path in any case.

Comment: Okay, Thanks I found out how to change the URI to absolut by adding "pack"  imgSrc = New BitmapImage(New Uri("pack://application:,,,/Resources/position.png", UriKind.Absolute))

Comment: WriteableBitmap looks good. I am still trying to wrap my head around "BackBufferStride" and "BackBuffer" but Thanks for the hint

Comment: There's a basic example (should get you started) and a decent description in the docs I linked. Do consider the Image DPI (see what the Dpi parameters have been set to in that example. There's a reason for that, but it doesn't apply to every context).

Answer (score 0):

The probably most simple way to change one or two of the colors of a black and white image is to use a `FormatConvertedBitmap` with a paletted pixel format and a two color palette:

```c#
// the source bitmap, no matter if B/W or anything else
BitmapSource source = ...;

// the target colors
var palette = new BitmapPalette(new List<Color> { Colors.Yellow, Colors.Red });

// the resulting bitmap
var twoColorImage = new FormatConvertedBitmap(source, PixelFormats.Indexed1, palette, 0);
image.Source = twoColorImage;
```